My sweelart2 is always in back of my v-dialog (vuetify 3)?
Why my sweetalert2 is always in back of my v-dialog in vuetify3 ?
Someone can help me to resolve this issue ?
I try some alternatives for sweetalert2 but i have no solution.
When i use sweetalert with v-dialog - the sweetalert stay on the back of v-dialog
<v-dialog
  v-model="dialog"
  width="auto"
>
  <v-card
    max-width="400"
    prepend-icon="mdi-update"
    text="Your application will relaunch automatically after the update is complete."
    title="Update in progress"
  >
    <template v-slot:actions>
      <v-btn
        class="ms-auto"
        text="Ok"
        @click="dialog = false"
      ></v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>


Did you check the CSS part (z-index) of your problem? Sweetalert might have a lower one than Vuetify's dialog. Inspect it with your browser devtools and write a higher specificity.

Thanks for your response ,
I add this to my CSS , and it's work :
.swal2-container {
z-index: 20000 !important;
}

OP solved the issue by using
.swal2-container {
  z-index: 20000 !important;
}


I see the solution for that :
i just add this to my CSS , and it's work :
.swal2-container {
  z-index: 20000 !important;
}

